# Adopted Internal SD Card is mounted twice

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, media-files, adoptable-storage

I've adopted my external SD card as internal storage with the new feature of Android 6.0 (Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini with CyanogenMod 13). Since I've done this I've recognized that my stock image galery app and music player (stock and every other I've tried) lists every media file on the external SD card twice.

I know that these media files (pictures, music,...) aren't really duplicates because if I remove one file, the "copy" is deleted too. If I add new files it gets "duplicated" as well.

So I've tried to figure out the problem. I've noticed that the content of my external SD card is mounted under `/sdcard/` with a symbolic link:

```
$ ls -la | grep "\->"
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root       21 2016-07-11 10:07 sdcard -> /storage/self/primary
```

And under `/storage/emulated/0/` (I can't execute the `ls` command in `/storage/emulated/`) which has exactly the same files and folders.

So is there any way to remove one of these mount points safely (I don't know which App uses which of these folders...)? Or is there any other way to tell the media library to only scan one of these directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I FOUND A SOLUTION. Using Solid explorer navigate to /storage/emulated and then open up the properties for the folder titled 0. Three dots in the top right corner and select "hide media" if it gives you a toast message saying there was an error, just do it again. So far Solid explorer is the only application I've found to give the solution. I'm not 100% sure what it's doing to the folder but it's working.

Any luck with this? I found found the same issue. If you could find a way to blacklist the mount point from the media cache it *should* work

Comment: This seems to work for me. I also get the error but the second time I  select "Hide Media" it works. Thanks!

Comment: Btw: it is possible to delete the Solid explorer afterwards. The change persists.